# How batch mv files to folders created and named by modification date?

Tags: rename, sort

I am quite new to the terminal stuff and I just couldn't find any answer on the aforementioned subject.

On my OS X, I have a folder with about 4000 pics that I'd like to move into folders that are named according to the modification date (not creation date) of the files. How can I accomplish this using the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

With OSX [stat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html):

```
for file in *; do
    dir="$(stat -t %Y%m%d%H%M%S -f %Sm -- "$file")"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir/$file"
done
```

---

With GNU stat (i.e. on Linux or Cygwin):

```
for file in *; do
    dir="$(stat -c %Y -- "$file")"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv -- "$file" "$dir/$file"
done
```

This will move each file into a directory named with its mtime (as an epoch).

If you want finer grained control over how the directory looks, you can use GNU date to reformat it by changing the assignment line to something like this:

```
dir="$(date -d @"$(stat -c %Y -- "$file")" +%F)"
```

See `man date` for information about date format specifications that you can use. In this case, `%F` is:

> %F     full date; same as %Y-%m-%d

Comment: OS/X has the BSD `stat` command with a different syntax.

Comment: Wow, I am impressed for the quick answer! Thanks! However, I get the message: "stat: illegal option -- c

Comment: Thanks to @Gilles for the modifications to use OSX `stat`.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'for (<*.jpg>) {
  $d=strftime"%Y-%m-%d",localtime((stat$_)[9]);
  mkdir$d;rename$_,"$d/$_" or warn "rename $_: $!\n"}'
```

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (*.jpg) {stat -F %F -A d +mtime -- $f && mkdir -p $d && mv -- $f $d}
```